# "Could not find a part of the path" error message in C#

Tags: c#, file-io

I am trying to remove spaces from a folder and its subfolder at the same time, but I get that error message. This is my code:

```
Directory.Move(@path, @path.Replace(" ", String.Empty));
```

Where *path* is C:\Users\meli\Desktop\New folder\New folder 2

I can only rename the subfolder "New folder 2" when "New folder" has no empty spaces.

How can I change both at once to remove white spaces?

Thanks!

Comment: Think about this logically: you're asking the OS to move `C:\Users\meli\Desktop\New folder\New folder 2` to `C:\Users\meli\Desktop\Newfolder\Newfolder2`. If `C:\Users\meli\Desktop\Newfolder` doesn't exist, how can it create a folder inside it called Newfolder2? You should work from the other direction and first rename the parent directory, then remove the child directories, and then rename their child directories, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I change both at once to remove white spaces?

You can't, you'll have to issue several commands

```
string p = @"c:\my path\with spaces";

p=p.TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar);

while(p != Path.GetPathRoot(p)){
  string dest = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(p), Path.GetFileName(p.Replace(" ", "")));

  if(!p.Equals(dest, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    Directory.Move(p, dest);
  p = Path.GetDirectoryName(p);
}
```

This takes the whole path and works backwards, first chopping off any trailing Directory separators which cause a problem for Path.GetX

Path.GetFileName can be used on directories too; it returns the chars after the last separator regardless of whether it's a file or directory.

We form a new destination name by stripping the spaces out of the last folder name only and leaving the rest of the path alone, by path.combine the parent directory plus the spaceless child folder

Finally we "go up a folder" which eventually causes us to reach the root and stop

Comment: Thank you so much it works fine though I get this message **System.IO.IOException:** 'Source and destination path must be different.' in the line `Directory.Move(p, dest);` I'm a newbie but you helped me understand

Comment: Put an `if` in to detect if the source and dest paths are different; only perform the move if they differ

Comment: Thank you, it was really helpful!